# What is the best way to speed up the templates loading time?

Tags: django

I have a project in which I need to save or display multiple forms after saving data when the page load it takes several time to display whole content, please help me to suggest the good package of compressing static files, I have already used django-compressor and django-assets packages but didn't get any success.Any ither things I can apply here ??

Comment: Just rendering some forms shouldn't have to take that long. What usually slows down page loading speed the most is large image/video files, and/or too much JavaScript. You can use tools like Lighthouse to find out where most of the time is being spent, and if you have any render blocking resources you can deal with. Also leveraging server and browser cache as much as possible can help you reduce loading speeds a bit.

Comment: I doubt your problem is that the compression isn't good enough, unless you're sending some really huge payloads together with the forms (like hundreds of MBs large videos etc.)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with 'it takes several time to display content', do you need to refresh your page multiple times or just it takes a few seconds to load the page?

If the rendering of the page takes a long time to render, you could try to find out why. Django debug toolbar (https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar) is a good tool to get some insights to find some improvements.

If it's not possible to improve the rendering and most of the requests are made to the same form/data then you can take a look at the Django cache framework (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache/)

Comment: There is nothing to find out because db queries running fast , and the only thing is that its having multiple forms . I have used django silk to analyze the time, and its only template loading time nothing else..thats why i am needing help ..I have applied cache,,but caching a page is not a good option

Comment: Hmm if its loading of the template that is slow and not the rendering, have you also enable caching for template loading: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.cached.Loader

Comment: Instead of template caching i want to use compressing and caching static files...I have used **CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage** , but in production its not loading compressed css and in my local its running well..any idea about this please??

Comment: Follow the link, its does not cache your page results. It caches the pre compiled templates that is used for rendering. You can still use compress with it.

Answer (score 0):

you can save the url of the static file in your database and using the url from the database you can load the files from the static folder . Also if it okay with your project you can use pagination

Comment: Have you tried it, because I never find this type of solution before